# Try to run crontab without success

Tags: python, linux, django, cron

I have project in django and I'm trying to run my crontask:

Here is my code in crontab:

```
30 12 * * * cd /path/to/file/in/project/apps && python import.py
```

but this code doesn't works for me.
Please for any hint.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What means *doesn't works for me*  any error messages or what?

Comment: @Jens normaly when I run command with `python import.py` is OK, but with crontab not working and I don't know why.

Comment: Check what's going wrong in /var/log/cron.log. Without error message it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the virtual environment activated when you run the command manually?
Try using the path of the virtualenv. You can also create a log to check the result of cront:

```
30 12 * * * path/to/app/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/app/import.py >> /path/yourcron.log  2>&1
```

Comment: I created .sh file `#!/bin/bash
#source $HOME/.profile
cd /nfs/koelner-philharmonie/koelner-philharmonie/staging
source venv/bin/activate
cd apps
python coda_import.py` but also without success

Comment: Did you try using the format I commented above? Run it in the terminal, if it works, it should also work on the cron. Don't forget to change the frequency for tests.
Did you set a log? Don't forget  the **2>&1** at the end